# Python - Forward fill with non gap date values with a loop condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a data frame as below.

```
Index Date Group Name
0   Oct-10  A   Sam
1   Oct-10  A   Sam
2   Dec-12  A   Sam
3   Dec-12  A   Sam
4   May-13  A   Peter
5   May-14  A   Peter
6   May-15  A   Chris
7   Apr-17  A   Chris
8   Apr-17  A   Sam
9   Jul-23  A   Sam
10  Dec-12  B   Peter
11  Dec-12  B   Peter
12  May-13  B   Peter
13  May-14  B   Peter
14  Apr-18  B   Sam
15  Jul-19  B   Sam
16  Jul-20  B   Sam
17  Jul-22  B   Sam
18  Jul-23  B   Sam
```

I want to forward fill the date values for every "Group" in such a way that every person start date should be forward filled.

Example : Group A, Sam started from Oct 2010, hence till from index 0 to 3, it should be Oct 2010 for him. Peter started on May 2013, so same May 2013 for index 4 & 5. However, again Sam comes in April 2017 so it should be April 2017 for index 8 & 9.

I am finding this is very difficult because Sam is appearing twice in group A. Your help will be highly appriciated to solve this. I am trying someting like below but not giving any results.

```
for every group in df["Group"]:
      df["date2"] = (df["Date"].groupby(["Name"]).transform(lambda x: x.ffill()))
```

the result I want is below

```
Index Date Group Name date2
0   Oct-10  A   Sam   Oct-10
1   Oct-10  A   Sam   Oct-10
2   Dec-12  A   Sam   Oct-10
3   Dec-12  A   Sam   Oct-10
4   May-13  A   Peter May-13
5   May-14  A   Peter May-13
6   May-15  A   Chris May-15
7   Apr-17  A   Chris May-15
8   Apr-17  A   Sam   Apr-17
9   Jul-23  A   Sam   Apr-17
10  Dec-12  B   Peter Dec-12
11  Dec-12  B   Peter Dec-12
12  May-13  B   Peter Dec-12
13  May-14  B   Peter Dec-12
14  Apr-18  B   Sam   Apr-18
15  Jul-19  B   Sam   Apr-18
16  Jul-20  B   Sam   Apr-18
17  Jul-22  B   Sam   Apr-18
18  Jul-23  B   Sam   Apr-18
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute a mask with [`shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) and [`any`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html), then use it to select the first values and [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.ffill.html):

```
cols = ['Group', 'Name']
m = df[cols].ne(df[cols].shift()).any(axis=1)

df['date2'] = df['Date'].where(m).ffill()
```

Output:

```
    Index    Date Group   Name   date2
0       0  Oct-10     A    Sam  Oct-10
1       1  Oct-10     A    Sam  Oct-10
2       2  Dec-12     A    Sam  Oct-10
3       3  Dec-12     A    Sam  Oct-10
4       4  May-13     A  Peter  May-13
5       5  May-14     A  Peter  May-13
6       6  May-15     A  Chris  May-15
7       7  Apr-17     A  Chris  May-15
8       8  Apr-17     A    Sam  Apr-17
9       9  Jul-23     A    Sam  Apr-17
10     10  Dec-12     B  Peter  Dec-12
11     11  Dec-12     B  Peter  Dec-12
12     12  May-13     B  Peter  Dec-12
13     13  May-14     B  Peter  Dec-12
14     14  Apr-18     B    Sam  Apr-18
15     15  Jul-19     B    Sam  Apr-18
16     16  Jul-20     B    Sam  Apr-18
17     17  Jul-22     B    Sam  Apr-18
18     18  Jul-23     B    Sam  Apr-18
```

Intermediates:

```
    Index    Date Group   Name   date2 Group_shift Name_shift  Group_eq_shift  Name_eq_shift      m
0       0  Oct-10     A    Sam  Oct-10        None       None            True           True   True
1       1  Oct-10     A    Sam  Oct-10           A        Sam           False          False  False
2       2  Dec-12     A    Sam  Oct-10           A        Sam           False          False  False
3       3  Dec-12     A    Sam  Oct-10           A        Sam           False          False  False
4       4  May-13     A  Peter  May-13           A        Sam           False           True   True
5       5  May-14     A  Peter  May-13           A      Peter           False          False  False
6       6  May-15     A  Chris  May-15           A      Peter           False           True   True
7       7  Apr-17     A  Chris  May-15           A      Chris           False          False  False
8       8  Apr-17     A    Sam  Apr-17           A      Chris           False           True   True
9       9  Jul-23     A    Sam  Apr-17           A        Sam           False          False  False
10     10  Dec-12     B  Peter  Dec-12           A        Sam            True           True   True
11     11  Dec-12     B  Peter  Dec-12           B      Peter           False          False  False
12     12  May-13     B  Peter  Dec-12           B      Peter           False          False  False
13     13  May-14     B  Peter  Dec-12           B      Peter           False          False  False
14     14  Apr-18     B    Sam  Apr-18           B      Peter           False           True   True
15     15  Jul-19     B    Sam  Apr-18           B        Sam           False          False  False
16     16  Jul-20     B    Sam  Apr-18           B        Sam           False          False  False
17     17  Jul-22     B    Sam  Apr-18           B        Sam           False          False  False
18     18  Jul-23     B    Sam  Apr-18           B        Sam           False          False  False
```

Answer (score 2):

> I am finding this is very difficult because Sam is appearing twice in group A.

Create a subgroup group to split 'Sam':

```
subgrp = df['Name'].ne(df['Name'].shift()).cumsum()
df['date2'] = df.groupby(['Group', 'Name', subgrp])['Date'].transform('first')
```

Output:

```
>>> out
      Date Group   Name   date2
0   Oct-10     A    Sam  Oct-10
1   Oct-10     A    Sam  Oct-10
2   Dec-12     A    Sam  Oct-10
3   Dec-12     A    Sam  Oct-10
4   May-13     A  Peter  May-13
5   May-14     A  Peter  May-13
6   May-15     A  Chris  May-15
7   Apr-17     A  Chris  May-15
8   Apr-17     A    Sam  Apr-17
9   Jul-23     A    Sam  Apr-17
10  Dec-12     B  Peter  Dec-12
11  Dec-12     B  Peter  Dec-12
12  May-13     B  Peter  Dec-12
13  May-14     B  Peter  Dec-12
14  Apr-18     B    Sam  Apr-18
15  Jul-19     B    Sam  Apr-18
16  Jul-20     B    Sam  Apr-18
17  Jul-22     B    Sam  Apr-18
18  Jul-23     B    Sam  Apr-18
```

About subgroup:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, subgrp.rename('Subgroup')], axis=1)
      Date Group   Name   date2  Subgroup
0   Oct-10     A    Sam  Oct-10         1
1   Oct-10     A    Sam  Oct-10         1
2   Dec-12     A    Sam  Oct-10         1
3   Dec-12     A    Sam  Oct-10         1
4   May-13     A  Peter  May-13         2
5   May-14     A  Peter  May-13         2
6   May-15     A  Chris  May-15         3
7   Apr-17     A  Chris  May-15         3
8   Apr-17     A    Sam  Apr-17         4
9   Jul-23     A    Sam  Apr-17         4
10  Dec-12     B  Peter  Dec-12         5
11  Dec-12     B  Peter  Dec-12         5
12  May-13     B  Peter  Dec-12         5
13  May-14     B  Peter  Dec-12         5
14  Apr-18     B    Sam  Apr-18         6
15  Jul-19     B    Sam  Apr-18         6
16  Jul-20     B    Sam  Apr-18         6
17  Jul-22     B    Sam  Apr-18         6
18  Jul-23     B    Sam  Apr-18         6
```